# Чат-бот присылает картинки при нажатии на кнопку, но не делает это по заданному графику

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Сделал телеграм-бота, который по нажатию кнопки присылает рандомную картинку из базы данных. Хочу добавить функцию, чтобы он в определенное время присылал рандомную картинку сам без нажатия на кнопку, но не работает. Выдает следующую ошибку: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'. Не понимаю как исправить?

```
    import telebot
    from telebot import types
    import random
    import schedule
    import time


    HTTP_API_TOKEN = '---'
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(HTTP_API_TOKEN)

    image_list = [ссылки на изображения]

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

    def start(message):
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДА!', callback_data='yes'))
        image_url = random.choice(image_list)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, image_url, reply_markup=keyboard)

    schedule.every().day.at("19:50").do(start)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

    
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=schedule